# Convert the syntax to async-await

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, async-await

I would like to convert the syntax to async-await. is it worthy? how can I do it?

```
// ---- UserRoutes ----
router.get('/user', middlewareJwt.jwtHandler, function (req, res) {
    UserService.get(req.userId,
        (user) => successCbk(res, 200, { user: user }),
        (err) => errorCbk(res, 400, err),
    );
});

// ---- UserService ----
const get = (userId, successCbk, errorCbk) => {
    return UserDAO.get(userId, successCbk, errorCbk);
};

// ---- userDAO ----
const get = (userId, successCbk, errorCbk) => {
    User.findOne({ "_id": userId }, function (err, user) {
        if(err) return errorCbk(err);
        user.password = "***";
        return successCbk(user);
    });
};
```

I tried to use async/await methods examples to rewrite the code but it threw errors so I wouldn't share the thing that does not work but I found this helpful/

```
router.get('/user/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await getUserFromDb({ id: req.params.id })
    res.json(user);
  } catch (e) {
    //this will eventually be handled by your error handling middleware
    next(e) 
  }
})
```

Next step was to implement it in a Router, Service, DAO model but then it didn't work...

Comment: Yes, you can convert this to use `async/await`. From the looks of it, you would actually want to do that within your `UserService` which you have not provided the code for. You have only provided code for the current usage of the service. I would also note that questions with no attempt typically end up being downvoted

Comment: `is it worthy?` that's an opinion `how can I do it?` using async / await syntax

Comment: @mwilson Thank you for the comment, I am new to stack overflow - no attempt means when I don't provide any info about the code I tried to write myself? UserService: **const get = (userId, successCbk, errorCbk) => {
    return UserDAO.get(userId, successCbk, errorCbk); };** and UserDAO: **const get = (userId, successCbk, errorCbk) => { User.findOne({ "_id": userId }, function (err, user) { if(err) return errorCbk(err); user.password = "xxx"; return successCbk(user); });};**

Answer (score 0):

This is to show how to use async/await in express routes.

```
router.get('/user', middlewareJwt.jwtHandler, async function (req, res) {
    try{
        var result = await UserService.get(req.userId);
        res(result);     
    }catch(error){
        res(error);
    }
});
```